# QListWidget.takeItem crashes with segfault

Tags: c++, qt4

I have snippet of code below:

```
while(ui->listWidget->count() > 0) {
     QListWidgetItem* aItem = ui->listWidget->takeItem(0);
}
```

in which I need to empty a QListWidget (the `listWidget` variable above).

Currently it crashes with a segfault if an item is focused inside it.

I assume that is a problem (the focusing part) but I just don't know *why*.

My end goals are:

1. If I can clear the widget, is this the best way to do it?
2. And if it's not, what is? I looked through the docs and couldn't find a `clear` method. I admit, I may have missed it, but I have spent several days on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QListWidget::clear()` exists. You might have missed it because it is a slot, not just a public function.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#clear

Comment: I did indeed miss it for that exact reason! Thanks for pointing it out!